# How to populate NULLs with nearest available value, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ID varchar(9),
    [year] varchar(7),
    Code varchar(9)
)

INSERT INTO #test (ID, [year], code)
VALUES ('8479', '2006', 'A'), ('8479', '2007', 'A'),
       ('8479', '2008', 'A'), ('8479', '2009', NULL),
       ('8479', '2010', NULL), ('8479', '2011_H1', NULL),
       ('8479', '2011_H2', NULL), ('8479', '2012_H1', 'B'),
       ('8479', '2012_H2', 'B'), ('8479', '2013_H1', 'B'),
       ('8479', '2013_H2', 'B'),
       ('5477', '2008', 'Z'), ('5477', '2009', 'Z'),
       ('5477', '2010', 'Z'), ('5477', '2011_H1', NULL),
       ('5477', '2011_H2', 'R')
```

I would like to populate the NULL code values with the nearest value available for that particular ID (nearest in order of year, and in any direction). In cases where the NULL is equidistant from values, the later year should take priority.

I would therefore want this result to be:

```
ID      year   Code
-------------------
8479    2006    A
8479    2007    A
8479    2008    A
8479    2009    A
8479    2010    A
8479    2011_H1 B
8479    2011_H2 B
8479    2012_H1 B
8479    2012_H2 B
8479    2013_H1 B
8479    2013_H2 B
5477    2008    Z
5477    2009    Z
5477    2010    Z
5477    2011_H1 R
5477    2011_H2 R
```

Some years are split into two - H1 followed by H2.

The number of NULL entries will vary for each ID.

I got as far as trying something along the lines of:

```
Update #test
set Code = (select top 1 b.Code 
            from #Test b
            where LEFT(#test.[year],4) > LEFT(b.[year],4) 
            and #test.ID = b.ID
            and b.Code IS NOT NULL)
Where Code IS NULL
```

but this obviously will not work and highlights the two main issues I'm having:

- What can I do to be able to assign order to 'year' entries with H1 and H2 suffixes?
- And how can I incorporate functionality that will find the nearest value regardless of direction?

I'm fairly new to this, so any help is much appreciated. I should add that I've inherited this database, and at the moment I'm not in a position to make any fundamental changes to the structure - I realise if my years were stored as dates then I would be half way there! Thanks.

Comment: are you looking to populate them in real time, or as a second pass with an `UPDATE`

Comment: Why you store a year as varchar? If you want to add the quarter use an additional column or a `datetime`/`date` in the first place. Your approach is slow, complicated and error-prone.

Comment: the latter, using UPDATE.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your comment. The year as varchar was not my design, I just wanted to find out if I can solve this in its current form. If not then I will use an additional column as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sets `Code` to the desired code, selected inside a sub-query from records having similar `ID` and `Code` being `not null` (**very important**), ordered by the `year` difference (the smaller the difference the better) and similar records are ordered by `year` descendingly, to choose the newer `year` in case of similar difference. This `update` is executed for each record which has a `null` `Code`:

```
update #Test
set Code = (select top(1) t.Code
            from #Test t
            where t.ID = #Test.ID and not (t.Code is null)
            ORDER BY Abs(Cast(Left(#test.year, 4) as smallint) - Cast(Left(t.year, 4) as smallint)), t.year desc)
where Code is null
```

However, this is problematic, because in the case when a given `ID` has only `null` `Code` values, the result will be `null` as well. Let's suppose we have a `'default'` code for such cases. Then, you can do this:

```
update #Test
set Code = ifnull((select top(1) t.Code
            from #Test t
            where t.ID = #Test.ID and not (t.Code is null)
            ORDER BY Abs(Cast(Left(#test.year, 4) as smallint) - Cast(Left(t.year, 4) as smallint)), t.year desc), 'default')
where Code is null
```

Comment: Thanks Lajos, this is almost what I need and close enough for my current purposes. The only slight issue is that by ordering by descending year (to prioritise the newer year) this can also reverse the H1 & H2 order. If this could be avoided then it would be a perfect solution.

Comment: In that case this might seem a feasible solution: ORDER BY Abs(Cast(Left(#test.year, 4) as smallint) - Cast(Left(t.year, 4) as smallint)), Cast(Left(t.year, 4) as smallint), t.year desc), which orders by difference, then by the effective year descendingly and the still equal prioritized records are ordered by year ascendingly. This way if the year of the record to be updated is 2006, then 2007 will precede both 2008 and 2005 and 2007_H1 will precede 2007_H2.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. Its quite slow method, but if you need to do it just once it should do.

```
UPDATE #test
    SET
        #test.code = (
            SELECT
                TOP(1)
                    ts.code
                FROM #test ts
                WHERE #test.ID = ts.ID
                    AND ts.code IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY Abs(Cast(Left(#test.[year], 4) as smallint) - Cast(Left(ts.[year], 4) as smallint))
            )
    WHERE #test.code IS NULL
```

Comment: the sub-query should check for Code IS NOT NULL ?  And you should return Code instead of year ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
; WITH test_data as
(
    SELECT ID, [year], [Code], rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [year])
    FROM    #Test
)
UPDATE  t
SET Code    = c.Code
FROM    test_data t
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT  TOP 1 x.Code
        FROM    test_data x
        WHERE   x.ID    = t.ID
        AND x.Code  is not null
        ORDER BY ABS(t.rn - x.rn)
    ) c
WHERE   t.Code  IS NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? I think the list in `CROSS APPLY` needs to supply one row for each updated row (more precisely each value to be inserted, once). This will supply just one.

Comment: yes. it works. CROSS APPLY in this case works in the same manner as your sub-query